# Session issue with Laravel 4

Tags: php, session, laravel, session-variables

I have been stuck since yesterday with an issue related to sessions in Laravel 4. I have a quite simple application that is a vehicle builder, you start with a base/chassis and you can add options to it to build your vehicle. I have a (restful) VehicleController controller with an action looking like this:

```
public function getShow($id)
{
    $excluded_parts = array();

    $the_vehicle                = Session::get('the_vehicle');
    $the_vehicle_built_image    = Session::get('the_vehicle_built_image');

    // Check if the selected vehicle changed
    if ($the_vehicle != $id) {
        // Forget the previous sessions
        Session::put('the_vehicle', '');
        Session::put('the_vehicle_built_image', '');
        Session::put('the_options', array());
        .......
```

Another method is used to add options:

```
public function getAddopt($id)
{
    // Get the current selected vehicle
    $the_vehicle = Session::get('the_vehicle');

    // Get the current selected vehicle's options
    $the_options = Session::get('the_options', array());

    ........
```

The strange behaviour is the following, when I load the `vehicles/show/1` page for the first time, no session seems to be set, when I try to add an option `vehicles/addopt/34`, I get an immediate error has `Session::get('the_vehicle')` supposed to be set in the previous action is empty.
This issue happens on the first load with a fresh session (I mean I need to close/reopen the browser to reproduce).
Do I miss something working with sessions in Laravel 4?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question. Where are you storing values in the session with `Session::put`? I see only one instance of it where you're trying to forget the previous session, in which case you should either use `Session::forget('the_vehicle');` or `Session::flush();` for all items.

Comment: The value is stored, just a bit later in the `getShow` action, this method is quite long, I didn't paste the whole thing.
You are right for the `Session::forget`, that is what I used previously, but trying debugging thinking they might be a problem with it, I tried just updating with empty strings with `Session::put`

Comment: Ah I see - and just to confirm, are you calling `Session::save()` after `Session::put`?

Comment: Thanks for your help Adam. `Session::save()` ? No I don't use it, and I don't see it in the doc http://laravel.com/docs/session

Comment: Could you show us the error?

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro the problme is solved, it was my mistake. There was no error just the session value not set. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry if people spent time on this issue, especially Adam, but I found my mistake. It was a typo in the layout, I had this `{ URL::to('/') }}` note the missing first curly-bracket. This broke session in IE only.
Thank you.